# Attempting pd.to_sql() asynchronously with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I'm trying to safely write dataframes to my PostgreSQL database, asynchronously, and in the most minimal way possible. I'm struggling to understand the documentation around this and was hoping someone here could help.

I have the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd 
import asyncio

x = 0

async def write_sql(engine):
    global x 
    x += 1
    print(f"Running {x}") 
    d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [3, 4, 5, 6]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)   
    df.to_sql(con=engine, name="test_data", if_exists="replace", index=False)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():    
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+asyncpg://user:pass@localhost:5432/postgres')
    t1 = datetime.now() 
    await asyncio.gather(write_sql(engine),write_sql(engine),write_sql(engine))
    t2 = datetime.now()
    delta = t2 - t1
    print(f"Took {delta} seconds")


if __name__=='__main__': 
    asyncio.run(main()) 
    print("Finished.")
```

Which works, however since I'm not using create_async_engine() I'm worried that this may not be the best way of solving this. Changing the code to use create_async_engine() instead throws me an 'AsyncEngine object has no cursor' error.

Anyone here that can throw some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

your code is not taking any benefits from async at all: the only call that would do a lot of I/O and therefore be able to to free your asyncio loop to do other tasks is `df.to_sql` - and it is synchronous and on the same thread. The extra "await asyncio.sleep(1)` just make your function hang on one extra second after the write is complete. (Other asyncio tasks could be running on this 1 second, if you need some cold confort).

If you are changing nothing else, *and* if you have some other async code that will actually work, you can use the async `loop.run_in_executor` call: that will make the sync `to_sql` method run in another thread, and the main thread is freed up for other tasks.

```
from functools import partial
...
async def write_sql(engine):
    global x 
    x += 1
    print(f"Running {x}") 
    d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [3, 4, 5, 6]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)   
    task_code = partial(df.to_sql,  name="test_data", if_exists="replace", index=False)
    loop = asynco.get_running_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, task_code)
    # drops the useless asyncio.sleep
```

However, as you said you want "safe execution" that is no guarranteed in multi-threaded code: if you have concurrent code - be it in other asyncio tasks or threads modifying the target dataframe while writting takes place, this won't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested in definite answer to this question, but I'm having a hard time. Nonetheless, my solution is just to make another thread supplemented with `multiprocessing.Queue()` prior to running `asyncio.run()` and then sending batches of data to that queue from within event loop with `queue.put(item)`. In the meantime, the worker thread runs `df.to_sql()` based on input values.

@jsbueno's answer is also an option, but I found it buggy when you have to do many inserts since it starts as many threads.